# Code to Reverse String not clearing up previous values

Tags: c, string

I am doing this programming problem where I have reverse string of about 30 characters for 10 test cases.

My code is this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main () {

    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);

    while (t--) {
        char str[30];

        scanf("%s",&str);

        char revStr[30];

        int len = strlen(str);
        int i = 0;
        int j = len-1;

        while (i < len) {
            revStr[i] = str[j];
            i++; j--;
        }

        printf("%s\n",revStr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output gets garbled up if the input string is larger than previous string.

For example,

if `last-string` had `6` characters, like `rocket\0` and `new-string`, which is `fun\0` has `3` characters, the output is `funket\0`.

Comment: The array name is equivalent to the address of the first element, so this `scanf("%s",&str);` should be `scanf("%s", str);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[30];
scanf("%s",&str);
           ^ don't pass address of array
```

Just this would work -

```
scanf("%29s",str);
```

Comment: Sorry, this change didn't give me the correct answer.

Comment: @RakeshNarang Add this line after the loop and before printing `revStr` **->** `revStr[i]='\0';` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);

```
while (t--) 
{
    char str[30] = { 0 };

    scanf("%s", &str);

    char revStr[30] = { 0 };

    int len = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;
    int j = len - 1;

    while (i < len) {
        revStr[i] = str[j];
        i++; j--;
    }

    printf("%s\n", revStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes

Firstly change `scanf("%s",&str);` to

```
scanf("%s",str);
```

Secondly, after the while loop, you are not making the last element `rev` string `\0`. Add this line before the printf statement.

```
revStr[i] = '\0';
```

This should solve your problem.